# Is there a way to find total time spent on a site?

Tags: feature-request, support

I can view the total number of days I visited Stack Overflow.

But is there any way I can find the total time (hours) I spent on Stack Overflow (from account creation to this point)?

I am in need to fill the total time I spend, in a form from a community.

Comment: There may be [some extensions for your browser](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20time%20spent%20on%20websites) that can help, to an extent, as well.

Answer (score 6):

Thankfully not. My boss would kill me if he saw the total time spent here ;).

There isn't really a way to determine how much time a user stares at a website. There are ways to come to a reasonable guess, but nothing concrete. You could measure the time between actions (comments, answers, flags, etc.), but how would you know you didn't actually do something else in between? The answer is no.

Comment: The same here if my boss saw it. But like flag history, is there any way that the person only can see it.?? Or will I get by contacting SO?

Comment: You could use SEDE or the API to see your own activity.

Comment: Not only activity I am asking. Include browsing. That is If I log on to SO, surfed many pages. But didn't made any actions. In such case, can I get that time too?

Comment: No. That would usually reside in the web server logs. You can't even extract a reliable metric from there, so it would be useless anyway.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the support. I think they keep track of the time because they use Ajax to check inbox message and rep change. So I thought they add the time on each request and perhaps they have a log. That's why I added by contacting SO team.

Comment: But that updates too if I am not staring at my screen.

Comment: Yah. That is also there. Also What if i just opened another tab and browse some other site. I accept. So I should have enter something like total_days_spend*9 or something to the hours. Am I right?

Comment: I tend to leave stuff left opened all day. My time/hours on SU by that metric would be insane.